# Can I make apps for ubuntu using a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, application-development

I develop windows software .

Does anyone know? how I can make application/software for *buntu using a windows pc?

Comment: Any perticular reason you can not install Ubuntu virtually and code from there with the tools Ubuntu supplies?

Answer (score 2):

Write them in a language available on both platforms.
One example would be to write it in Java.

Comment: Most all languages are available on both platforms. It doesn't mean that your application will immediately work on both, nor integrate well with the platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop in QT which while it does work on linux and windows, is far more native to linux then java is and can run in ubuntu easily. For example, the ubuntu one client is in qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do most of your development on Windows if you are making a cross-platform application (most open source toolkits and programming environments are cross-platform to some degree), but you would still need to test it on Ubuntu, of course.

If you don't like having a dedicated or dual boot system with Ubuntu, most testing can also happen in a virtual machine (if your software is not a hardware driver or such).

Most people I know do it the other way around though—code on Ubuntu/linux and also test/release on Windows...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I am developing one right know. Is not even a browser app, but a standalone one.

I use Netbeans. The project folder is stored on a shared directory that I can access from my Windows 7 or my Ubuntu 12.04. I compile and run from any of the systems without a problem.

You do have to install Netbeans or your IDE of choice in both systems and make sure to use the same version or some warnings will start popping in one and not in the other, that will probably pop in the other if you correct them in the one :p.

If you want to use something different from java, that creates a binary unique to the system, then you do have to specify a different directory for the output compiled binary, one for each system you want, but you can still use the same directory for the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Its not as simple as that, what language do you use? Will the program need access to the users printer or internet and lots of other little things like that to consider, you cant just code a windows app and cast the linux portius spell im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a c# guy you could try out [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). Developing .net on windows with visual studio and port it to gtk. Monodevelop has an Visual Designer to create Ubuntu look and Feel. In my opinion not the way Microsoft Visual Studio/Expression Blend has, but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

quickly can be used to develop in lots of platforms, just create the project using Ubuntu, install Python and PyGTK on Windows and ready!

If you don't know how to develop in Python, the official documentation and Ubuntu Developer portal can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many choice for it . I would like to suggest qt toolkit because it is recommended toolkit for ubuntu and it provide native interface in other platforms too .